# Setting a different "From" address for mail sent via Gmail using C#

Tags: c#, .net, email, gmail

I am using a simple mail sender class that uses the `System.Net.Mail`. I need to update my application so various users can send email via it (using the same smtp account) but the "From" address should be of the user who is causing it to be sent. I tried setting the `From` property of `MailMessage`, and sending the from address into the constructor of `MailMessage` but nose of those worked. I am sure I am missing something simple or not understanding how the mail API works. Can anyone help?

Here my MailSender class that basically wraps the `MailMessage`, `NetworkCredential` and `SmtpClient` to provide one simple mail sending interface.

```
class MailSender
{
    private NetworkCredential credential;
    private String SenderAddress;
    private SmtpClient client;

    public MailSender(String ServerURL, String account, String password, String FromAddress = null, int port = -1, bool UseSSL = true)
    {
        if (port > 0)
        {
            client = new SmtpClient(ServerURL, port);
        }
        else
        {
            client = new SmtpClient(ServerURL);
        }
        credential = new NetworkCredential(account, password);
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.EnableSsl = UseSSL;
        client.Credentials = credential;

        if (FromAddress != null)
        {
            SenderAddress = FromAddress;
        }
        else
        {
            SenderAddress = account;
        }
    }

    public bool SendMessage(String to, String subject, String body)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(SenderAddress, to, subject, body);
            message.From = new MailAddress(SenderAddress, "tester");

            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            client.Send(message);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: IIRC, GMail modifies it according to your settings of the account.

Comment: It might very well be that Google will not allow you to send mail from accounts other than the credentials you pass in for authentication.

Comment: @leppie and @Mikael Svenson: tried it with our office's smtp as well. Same results.

Comment: It might be that both Google and your office SMTP refuse to relay http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay

Comment: @Mikael Svenson, @leppie, @smirkingman: You are right. GMail does not allow setting any other from address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found out the answer by testing with another SMTP server. This is actually caused by GMail not allowing any other from address. This works fine with other SMTP servers.

Thanks to leppie, Mikael Svenson and smirkingman for their suggestions.

Comment: It's likely that your mails get blocked as spam if you forge the sender address/use a server which isn't allowed for that domain.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: No. All email were sent and made their way to my inbox (and other inboxes) fine. They just had the "from" address the same as the GMail account that was used to send them instead of the address I wanted it to have. Switching to another smtp server removed the problem.

Comment: Of course the mails where google changed the From were ok since smtp server and email match.  But if you use another smtp which doens't it the from the mail might be filtered. In particular if the domain of the email in the `From` field uses `SPF`.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: This is not happening and GMail is not marking any mail received where actual sender and from address are different as spam. At least not for the mails I have sent while testing. In any case, this is irrelevant to the problem at hand IMHO. But thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 3):

this thread is a bit old but I just found out that to be able to have a different address in the from field using Google servers to send emails from a script, you have to add that address to the Send As list in the Gmail account used to authenticate.
So login to the Gmail account of the user you use to authenticate against Google servers, go to Config, Accounts and add the desired from addresses to the Send As list by following the 3 simple steps provided.
That solved my problem
Hope it helps someone
Josu

Answer (score 2):

Gmail not allowing any other from address.
It might help you, you can change the replay in this way:

mail.ReplyTo = new MailAddress ( "SomeOtherAddress@mycompany.com");