# How do you get e-mails to use the "From" parameter in WebMail.Send with MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, smtp, contact-form, mailmessage, webmail

I have set up a contact form on my site for users to send messages to me to get in contact.

The WebMail.Send() method of sending a message works fine but the problem is, when I receive the e-mail it is received from the e-mail that I have defined for the SMTP client.

The call for sending the mail looks like this:

```
WebMail.Send(mailMessage.To[0].Address, mailMessage.Subject, mailMessage.Body, mailMessage.From.Address);
```

What I want to know is how do I get the messages to send using this method but receive to me with the MailMessage's from address rather than my SMTP account address?

Answer (score 1):

```
mailMessage.From = New MailAddress("whatever@yourdomain.com")
```

Comment: also, possible dup. see this SO post for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243300/setting-a-different-from-address-for-mail-sent-via-gmail-using-c-sharp

Comment: I have already implemented this. This is the mailMessage.From address already. However it uses the address form the SMTP account.