# C# SMTP Client, setting Sent From parameter

Tags: c#, email

I am using SmtpClient to send email like this

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("email-from@gmail.com", "email-to@gmail.com", "Contact from " + emailFrom, text);
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 587;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailAccount, accountPass);
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Send(mail);
```

This is working fine, I am receiving emails but I receive email from emailAccount address variable. I want to recieve emails from the 'From' field of message i.e email-from@gmail.com

Is it possible?

Comment: The chosen answer on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243300/setting-a-different-from-address-for-mail-sent-via-gmail-using-c-sharp?rq=1) question imply GMail's SMTP server doesn't allow changing the From field.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like these.

```
mail.From  = fromEmailAddress; // Your variable that contains from address
```

for more details see.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx

[Sending Email to multiple Recipients with MailMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23484503/sending-email-to-multiple-recipients-with-mailmessage)

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/smtpmail-and-mail-message-send-mails-in-net/

Comment: I see the email address which was used to send the email but not that which user types in the from field in the HTML form.